# How fast should you read a textbook?

Tags: general

I am a mathematician that is going to switch subjects to theoretical computer science. From maths I am used to reading papers and books very slowly (almost as slow as possible) and I usually expect to need an hour per page, so reading a book of 500pages is almost impossible (and I never did). But now I am reading a book about theoretical computer science and I can go way faster (rather 5pages/hour for a book that is not just an introduction). But from my viewpoint it feels wrong to be that fast (or maybe I am even slow) and I wondered how careful/slow you should usually read textbooks in (theoretical) cs. Of course the speed varies from what you want to learn, but let's say if you just want to understand the material (as opposed to reproduce it without looking it up).

I was reading maths papers too fast for a long time until somebody told me that this is too fast. I was wondering if I am doing a mistake of this kind too now.

Comment: One hour per page? You mathematicians must either use very small fonts, or very large pages...

Comment: That is actually what the author usually recommends at the beginning of a book in the "How to read this book" section

Comment: @Roland Don't let the author tell you how to read their book! What do they know about what you want to use the book for? I also think it would help if you're more precise about what your goal is in reading the text. For example, in the context of [Bloom's taxonomy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bloom's_taxonomy), "understanding" is relatively shallow and usually refers just to the ability to have a meaningful conversation about the material, and not to applying the material. But you may have something else in mind.

Comment: @Discretelizard I had a look at Bloom's taxonomy. For my maths studies I would say that "understanding" such that you can have a meaningful conversation about the material is probably 90% of the work. If you understand it, you can probably apply it etc and if you cant, you probably did not understand it. Maybe this causes the confusion of my question. I was always quite thankful if the author told me how to read it.